# Add column in SQL

Tags: microsoft-access, sql

I am currently learning SQL, and my current question is. Is it bad practice to have the word "COLUMN" after add when you want to add a column in SQL code?

```
ALTER TABLE FICTION
add COLUMN Best_Seller CHAR;
```

Or is it better practice to do this?

```
ALTER TABLE FICTION
add Best_Seller CHAR;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many SQL engines support both formats (SQLite, Postgre, MySQL, Oracle), but some (notably [MS SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)) support ADD only. So in a sense, ADD is a little more universal than ADD COLUMN.

- Both format are frequently encountered in code snippets around the web.
- ALTER TABLE syntax tend to differ from engine to engine and it is normal to refer to documentation when first using those commands in a new engine.
- ADD COLUMN may better show your intentions, at a quick glance, that you're adding a column and not a constraint, index or something else.
- It's hard to justify ADD for the saved typing alone since these statements are not written as often as SELECT or UPDATE statements.
- If your find one syntax more readable to you and others that may use your database, that should count for something too.

For these reasons, it seems to come down to personal preference. But I feel ADD COLUMN is clearer without any downside to the added verbosity except incompatibility with SQL Server.